# What jQuery / JavaScript files to define $?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a simple sliding Div over another div.
This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cf7u73pn/2/) is exactly what I want to make, but since I'm new in this world of coding, I get the warning `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` after copying the codes to my own files.

```
<div class="hidden" id="slide">INFORMATION ABOUT IMAGE APPEARS ON CLICK</div> 
<div class="image"><br>THERE'S A NICE IMAGE HERE</div>

$(document).ready(function() {$('#slide').click(function() {
var hidden = $('.hidden');
if (hidden.hasClass('visible')) {
  hidden.animate({"top": "160px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
} 
else {
    hidden.animate({"top": "0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
}
});
});
```

I now understand that I have to link a/several (?) file(s) in my HTML head to define my `$`. Can someone please help me find the right files and tell me how to link these into my html?

Comment: You are at level 1 in programming, first of all take courses or watch videos, otherwise you will struggle a lot

Comment: You need to include the library/plugin file/s to use it. Here, you haven't included the jQuery thus the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery video tutorial resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401810/jquery-video-tutorial-resources)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're using jQuery and didn't import it.
You need to add the jQuery library before being able to use it :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The (single) jQuery distribution file, available [here](http://jquery.com/download/) or on several CDNs.

Here's the code in your question, with jQuery added, just to show that it no longer complains about `$` not being defined. It still doesn't work, because it's really hard to click a hidden element, but it's a step forward.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slide').click(function() {
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')) {
      hidden.animate({
        "top": "160px"
      }, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
      hidden.animate({
        "top": "0px"
      }, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="hidden" id="slide">INFORMATION ABOUT IMAGE APPEARS ON CLICK</div>
<div class="image">
  <br>THERE'S A NICE IMAGE HERE</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I recommend working through tutorials, which can introduce concepts, etc. SO is for Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load jQuery before using $

try adding this before you use jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]
Add Jquery like in the photo, or add it as external resource